# How to align items in Row with ListView.builder()

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to make design similar to this:

[image]

But getting this as the output:

[image]

below is my code that I implemented:

```
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 5,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          itemCount: interests.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return interests[index];
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

here interests is the list:
like this:

```
List<Widget> interests = [
  OutlinedButton.icon(
    onPressed: null,
    icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
    label: const Text('Socializing'),
  ),
  OutlinedButton.icon(
    onPressed: null,
    icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
    label: const Text('Community Work'),
  ),
  OutlinedButton.icon(
    onPressed: null,
    icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
    label: const Text('Photography'),
  ),
...
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?
p.s. If I remove expanded widget it causes error

I am implementing all this in a Dialog > SingleChildScrollableView > Column

Comment: Looking at your design you might want to use Wrap instead https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using ListView, use `Wrap` by wrapping with a scrollable widget like `SingleChildScrolView` if needed.

```dart
Wrap(
  children: interests,
)
```

Find more about [`Wrap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)